# How to make a navigation drawer outside of the Appbar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a container which contains a navigation drawer and a search box. I don't want to use an Appbar. I achieved the search box, but I cannot make a navigation drawer without an Appbar. I want it to look like the google maps app.

I have tried using Row(), Scaffold(), Align(), etc. but I haven't been a able to achieve it.

Comment: you can make appbar transparent and hide the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Scaffold, add a Drawer and open it programmatically using ScaffoldState.openDrawer(). You don't have to add an AppBar if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

for me I used this code `Scaffold(drawer:Drawer(),body:InkWell(ontap(){ Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();},child: const Icon(Icons.Menu,color:Colors.white)));` and work very well.